# Phaser Scrollable Text Box Tutorial not working on mobile

Tags: phaser-framework

I recreated the [scrolling text box tutorial](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/input/dragging/scrolling-text-box) in my game. However, it is running a bit glitchy on mobile. For example, if I swipe up, the text first goes down for a second and then follows my finger up. You’ll see the problem if you open the tutorial on mobile. Any thoughts? I copied my code below.

```
var graphics = scene.make.graphics();

graphics.fillRect(x, y + 10, width, height - 20);

var mask = new Phaser.Display.Masks.GeometryMask(scene, graphics);

var text = scene.add.text(x + 20, y + 20, content, { 

  fontFamily: 'Assistant', 

  fontSize: '28px', 

  color: '#000000', 

  wordWrap: { width: width - 20 } 

}).setOrigin(0);

text.setMask(mask);

var minY = height - text.height - 20;

if (text.height <= height - 20) {

  minY = y + 20;

}

//  The rectangle they can 'drag' within

var zone = scene.add.zone(x, y - 3, width, height + 6).setOrigin(0).setInteractive({useHandCursor: true});

zone.on('pointermove', function (pointer) {

  if (pointer.isDown) {

    text.y += (pointer.velocity.y / 10);

    text.y = Phaser.Math.Clamp(text.y, minY, y + 20);

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My solution is using "pointer.y" instead of "pointer.velocity.y".

Here is my code:

```
var previousPointerPositionY;
var currentPointerPositionY;

zone.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
    previousPointerPositionY = pointer.y;
});

zone.on('pointermove', function (pointer) {

    if (pointer.isDown) {
        currentPointerPositionY = pointer.y;

        if(currentPointerPositionY > previousPointerPositionY){
            text.y += 5;
        } else if(currentPointerPositionY < previousPointerPositionY){
            text.y -= 5;
        }

        previousPointerPositionY = currentPointerPositionY;
        text.y = Phaser.Math.Clamp(text.y, -360, 150);
    } 
});
```